# How to run 'ufw' without interactive mode?

Tags: ufw

I want to run `ufw` Uncomplicated Firewall from python script but it usually runs in interactive mode. Example:

```
subprocess.check_output(["ufw", "enable"])
```

Has the following output:

```
'Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? Aborted'
```

Is there a way to run `ufw` without interactive mode?

Comment: Try `ufw --force enable`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use

```
ufw --force enable
```

You may want to have a look at the Gufw source code, it's written in Python. 
At least in Ubuntu 14.10 the  calls to `ufw` are in the file `gufw/model/ufw_backend.py`.

You can download the source code using

```
apt-get source gufw
```

Comment: Example: `sudo ufw --force-enable reset`

Comment: @Underverse it should actually be `sudo ufw --force reset`

Answer (score 0):

Despite it's an old question, this might be helpful for others. It's possible to use `--force` option for deleting rules.
for example:

```bash
# ufw --force delete 1
```

I wrote this code snippet to delete all 20 top rules:

```bash
# for i in `seq 20`; do ufw --force delete 1; done
```